# How to pass on capitalized inputs into a form?

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui

Hello programming community,
after a long research I am still struggling with manipulating/formatting inputs before passing them into a form. The if the user is typing **j**ohn **d**oe it should be formatted into **J**ohn **D**oe.

the Form Date:

```
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
    dob: "",
    street: "",
    housenumber: "",
    housenumberadd: "",
    plz: "",
    city: "",
    email: "",
    phonenr: "",
    pid: "",
    password: "",
  });
  console.log(formData);
```

the variables:

```
  const [firstname, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [validFirstName, setValidFirstName] = useState(false);
  const [FirstNameFocus, setFirstNameFocus] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const result = FIRSTNAME_REGEX.test(firstname);
    //console.log("Firstname: " + firstname + " " + result);
    //console.log(firstname)
    setValidFirstName(result);
  }, [firstname]);
```

the change function:

```
  function handleChange(event) {

    setFormData((prevFormData) => {
      return {
        ...prevFormData,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
      };
    });
  }
```

the submittion:

```
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    setFirstName(
      firstname.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + firstname.slice(1, firstname.length)
    );
    e.preventDefault();
    const v1 = FIRSTNAME_REGEX.test(firstname);
    const v2 = PWD_REGEX.test(password);
    const v3 = LASTNAME_REGEX.test(lastname);
    const v5 = STREET_REGEX.test(street);
    const v6 = NUMBER_REGEX.test(housenumber);
    const v7 = PLZ_REGEX.test(plz);
    const v8 = PID_REGEX.test(pid);
    const v9 = MAIL_REGEX.test(email);
    if (!v1 || !v2 || !v3 || !v5 || !v6 || !v7 || !v8 || !v9) {
      setErrMsg("Invalid input");
      return;
    }
    setSuccess(true);
    try {
      const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
        email: formData.email,
        password: formData.password,
        options: {
          data: {
            first_name: formData.firstname,
            last_name: formData.lastname,
            date_of_birth: formData.dob,
            street_form: formData.street,
            house_number: formData.housenumber,
            house_number_add: formData.housenumberadd,
            zip_code: formData.plz,
            city_form: formData.city,
            phone_nr: formData.phonenr,
            passport_ID: formData.pid,
          },
        },
      });
      alert("Check your email for the verification link");
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  };
```

the input:

```
            <FormControl sx={{ m: 1 / 2 }}>
              <TextField
                label="First name"
                fullWidth="true"
                type="text"
                name="firstname"
                id="firstname"
                required
                autoFocus
                color={validFirstName ? "success" : "error"}
                onInput={handleChange}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setFirstName(e.target.value);
                }}
                inputRef={userRef}
                inputProps={{
                  startAdornment: (
                    <InputAdornment position="start"></InputAdornment>
                  ),
                  style: { textTransform: "capitalize" },
                }}
                onFocus={() => setFirstNameFocus(true)}
                onBlur={() => setFirstNameFocus(false)}
                helperText={
                  !FirstNameFocus
                    ? ""
                    : validFirstName
                    ? ""
                    : "3 to 24 characters. Must begin with a letter. Letters and hyphens are allowed."
                }
              />
            </FormControl>
```

as you can see I have tried to slice the variable an put is back together but this does not work, I have also tried to use this method at different places e.g. in the input filed and within the change function but theses did not worked out either.
The textTransform does only capitalize the text within the input field but does not pass it on.

Comment: YOu can extend the `handleChange` function to make the text camelCase for the name.